# Sorting an array of objects for a blockchain like data structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, blockchain

I have an array of objects that looks the following:

```js
var arr = [
  { id: 1, prev: 0 },
  { id: 4, prev: 3 },
  { id: 3, prev: 2 },
  { id: 8, prev: 7 }
  { id: 5, prev: 4 },
  { id: 7, prev: 6 },
  { id: 6, prev: 5 },
  { id: 2, prev: 1 }
]
```

I am getting this array from the server and there is no guarantees on the order. I want to sort the array such that, each object is followed by the object whose `prev` property is the same as the `id` property of the previous object.

For example,

```js
// Given the following array
var arr = [
  { id: 1, prev: 0 },
  { id: 4, prev: 3 },
  { id: 3, prev: 2 },
  { id: 8, prev: 7 }
  { id: 5, prev: 4 },
  { id: 7, prev: 6 },
  { id: 6, prev: 5 },
  { id: 2, prev: 1 }
]

function compareFn(a, b) {
}

var sortedArray = arr.sort( compareFn );

console.log(sortedArray);
/* Should be
[
  { id: 1, prev: 0 },
  { id: 2, prev: 1 },
  { id: 3, prev: 2 },
  { id: 4, prev: 3 }
  { id: 5, prev: 4 },
  { id: 6, prev: 5 },
  { id: 7, prev: 6 },
  { id: 8, prev: 7 }
]
*/
```

I have tried the following `compareFn()`

```js
function compareFn(a, b) {
  return a.id === b.prev ? 1 : -1
}
```

However this results in:

```js
[
  { 'id': 1, 'prev': 0 },
  { 'id': 3, 'prev': 2 },
  { 'id': 4, 'prev': 3 },
  { 'id': 8, 'prev': 7 },
  { 'id': 5, 'prev': 4 },
  { 'id': 6, 'prev': 5 },
  { 'id': 7, 'prev': 6 },
  { 'id': 2, 'prev': 1 }
]
```

I am quite certain that this is because of the equality in the sorting function instead of the usual `>/</<=/>=` but I don't know where the problem is.

I could sort using a loop but I want to better understand how the `.sort` method works.

Any help would be wonderful.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use a sort function like this - if you select 2 objects at random from the list you won't be able to say which is 'larger', you need to walk the blockchain one element at a time to find where a certain object belongs (unless you know the id values will always come back in order, in which case you should state this in your question).

Comment: What determines the initial object in the array? Will it always have a `prev` of 0, or do you have to do something more complicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `prev` values won't be dependably in order (since it's a blockchain, after all):

I wouldn't use the built-in `sort` for this - it requires a consistent compare function, but each item's position depends on the *last* sorted item's position. It'd be quite convoluted to use `.sort` for this. Rather, first create a lookup table (an object indexed by `prev`), then iterate starting a a `prev` of 0, finding the appropriate object in the lookup table, until all objects are in the new array:

```js
var arr = [
  { id: 1, prev: 0 },
  { id: 4, prev: 3 },
  { id: 3, prev: 2 },
  { id: 8, prev: 7 },
  { id: 5, prev: 4 },
  { id: 7, prev: 6 },
  { id: 6, prev: 5 },
  { id: 2, prev: 1 }
];

const itemsByPrev = arr.reduce((a, item) => {
  a[item.prev] = item;
  return a;
}, {});

const sorted = [];
let lastId = 0;
const { length } = arr;
while (sorted.length < length) {
  const obj = itemsByPrev[lastId];
  sorted.push(obj);
  lastId = obj.id;
}
console.log(sorted);
```

Another bonus of using this method is that it has `O(n)` complexity, compared to `.sort`, which has `O(n log n)` complexity.

Comment: where do you know from that prev is zero for starting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
// Given the following array
var arr = [
  { id: 1, prev: 0 },
  { id: 4, prev: 3 },
  { id: 3, prev: 2 },
  { id: 8, prev: 7 },
  { id: 5, prev: 4 },
  { id: 7, prev: 6 },
  { id: 6, prev: 5 },
  { id: 2, prev: 1 }
]
 
 
 arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id - b.id;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: The OPs requirements are: _I want to sort the array such that, each object is followed by the object whose prev property is the same as the id property of the previous object_, this just sorts the objects by the `.id` property

Answer (score 0):

You could store all items with their previous id as key in a map, get the nodes without parent and iterate these parents and get the children as a sorted array.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, prev: 0 }, { id: 4, prev: 3 }, { id: 3, prev: 2 }, { id: 8, prev: 7 }, { id: 5, prev: 4 }, { id: 7, prev: 6 }, { id: 6, prev: 5 }, { id: 2, prev: 1 }],
    map = array.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.prev, o), new Map),
    first = array.reduce((s, { id }) => (s.delete(id), s), new Set([...map.keys()])),
    result = [];

first.forEach(id => {
    var temp;
    while (map.has(id)) {
        result.push(temp = map.get(id));
        id = temp.id;
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
function compareFn(a, b) {
  return a.prev - b.prev;
}
```

or

```
function compareFn(a, b) {
  return a.id - b.id;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

looks like all you need to do is this :

```
function compareFn(a, b) {
   return a.prev - b.prev
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I can see previous value is always less than id. So, Ideally sorting the object by its key will work correctly.

```
keysSorted = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.key - b.key;
});
```